# Messed up Folder structure. Is there a way to delete the empty subfolders except one?

Tags: directory-structure, file-management

After trying to reorganize my movie folder on my Debian machine, I ended up with a structure like this:

```
├── Universal.Love(2017)(1080p)
│   └── Universal.Love(2017)(1080p)
│       └── Universal.Love(2017)(1080p)
│           └── Universal.Love(2017)(1080p).mkv
│               └── Universal.Love(2017)(1080p).mkv.mkv
├── Unknown.User.2014.German.DTS.DL.1080p.BluRay.x264-EXQUiSiTE
│   └── exq-unknownuser-1080p
│       └── exq-unknownuser-1080p
│           └── exq-unknownuser-1080p
│               └── exq-unknownuser-1080p.mkv
├── Unsane.2018.1080p.BluRay.x264-DRONES
│   └── Unsane.2018.1080p.BluRay.x264-DRONES
│       └── Unsane.2018.1080p.BluRay.x264-DRONES
│           └── Unsane.2018.1080p.BluRay.x264-DRONES
│               └── Unsane.2018.1080p.BluRay.x264-DRONES.mkv
├── Untitled (2017)
│   └── Untitled.2017.WEBDL-1080p
│       └── Untitled.2017.WEBDL-1080p
│           └── Untitled.2017.WEBDL-1080p
│               └── Untitled.2017.WEBDL-1080p.mkv
```

Is there a possibility to only end up with the .mkv inside ONE subfolder

Comment: How should the subfolder and the file be named? Should it be `foo/foo.mkv` or `foo.mkv/foo.mkv.mkv` or `foo/foo.mkv.mkv`?

Answer (score 1):

```bash
shopt -s globstar nullglob
for dir in ./*/; do
    for file in "$dir"/**/*.mkv; do
        [ ! -f "$file" ] && continue
        mv -i "$file" "$dir"
    done
done
```

The above double loop would solve your issue.

It does this by iterating over the directories in the current directory (which is supposed to be the directory that holds all those top-level directories).  For each directory, all `.mkv` files from anywhere below that directory are moved up into the subdirectory.  This is done by means of the `**` glob in `bash` which matches recursively into subdirectories.

The `globstar` shell option is enabled to enable the use of `**`, and `nullglob` is also enabled so that the loops don't run at all if there are no matches of the given patterns.

You may then delete empty directories with

```
find . -type d -empty -delete
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```bsh
find . -mindepth 3 -type f -name "*.mkv" -exec sh -c '
    f="$1"; IFS=/ && set -- $f; echo mv -t "$2" "$f"
' find-sh {} \;
```

(How to find the first subfolder: [via](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24632045/7365127))

Remove the `echo` when you checked the output.
This will move all *.mkv files that are deeper than 2 levels in the structure to the first subdirectory of your current dir.

Then you might want to remove the empty directories:

```bsh
find . -type d -empty -delete
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d ! -name '.' | while read -r folder; do
        find $folder -type f -name '*.mkv' -exec mv {} $folder \;
        find $folder -type d -empty -delete
done
```

- 1st `find` will get all the primary directories list.
- 2nd `find` will move the available .mkv file to the primary directory.
- 3rd `find` will delete all empty directories inside the primary directory.

Note: we can also move the 3rd `find` out of `while` loop to delete all empty directories in one shot.